# Marshaling - conversion std::vector<char> to string^ And conversely

Tags: c++, c++-cli, marshalling

I use 2 method for these conversion

// Vector to String.

```
VectorToString(std::vector<char> data)
{
  const char* newData = &data[0];
  String ^result;
  result = marshal_as<String^>(newData);
  return result;
}
```

// String to vector

```
 StringToVector(String ^ data)
{
  marshal_context ctx;
  IntPtr p = Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(data);
  const char* pAnsi = static_cast<const char*>(p.ToPointer());
  // use pAnsi
  std::vector<char> result;
  result.assign(pAnsi, pAnsi + strlen(pAnsi));
  Marshal::FreeHGlobal(p);
  return result;
}
```

with 2 above function I can doing convert.
can you tell me these conversion is correct? or not?
actually, this way for convert std::vector to String is best way?

Comment: Why don't you use `std::string`? `marshal_as` supports these out of the box. `StringToHGlobalAnsi`/`FreeHGlobal` is quite clunky, you could `marshal_as<std::string>` then copy to the vector if you really need that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must be add #include msclr/marshal_cppstd.h

vector to String ^

```
vector<char> data;// this is be initialize
std::string myString = std::string(begin(data), end(data));
String^ result = marshal_as<String^>(myString);
```

string ^ to vector

```
marshal_context context;
std::vector<char> myVector;
const char* afterConvert = context.marshal_as<const char*>(data);
myVector.assign(afterConvert , afterConvert + strlen(afterConvert));
```